# Swift link in a Annotation -> Webview

Tags: dictionary, webview, hyperlink, swift, annotations

I try to find a way to add a link to a Annotation in Swift MapFramework, this link should forward the user to a WebView, as far i see i can't find any way to add a "touchable" link into a Annotations SubTitle

Here is my Code yet

```
class CustomPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    var imageName: String!
}




var info1 = CustomPointAnnotation()
info1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(42, -84)
info1.title = "Info1"
info1.subtitle = "Subtitle"
info1.imageName = "1.png"

var info2 = CustomPointAnnotation()
info2.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(32, -95)
info2.title = "Info2"
info2.subtitle = "Subtitle"
info2.imageName = "2.png"


func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
    if !(annotation is CustomPointAnnotation) {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "test"

    var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
    if anView == nil {
        anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        anView.canShowCallout = true
    }
    else {
        anView.annotation = annotation
    }

    //Set annotation-specific properties **AFTER**
    //the view is dequeued or created...

    let cpa = annotation as CustomPointAnnotation
    anView.image = UIImage(named:cpa.imageName)

    return anView
}
```

Is there maybe a way to use the UIGestureRecognizer for this?

I already tried it like

```
var longpress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "newInformation:")
            longpress.minimumPressDuration = 2.0
            info1.addGestureRecognizer(longpress)
```

But ending with "ViewController.CustomPointAnnotation does not have a member named addGestureRecognizer"

Comment: Many of the questions you are asking are already answered either in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/) or on SO.  In the docs, search for MKMapView class reference or read the [Location and Maps Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).  The answers on SO at the moment will mostly be in Objective-C but will work _exactly_ the same in Swift (just need to translate the language).

Comment: For this current question, the typical approach is to add a callout accessory button by setting the view's leftCalloutAccessoryView or rightCalloutAccessoryView.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25202613/mapkit-in-swift-part-2 for an example.  When the button is tapped, map view will call the calloutAccessoryControlTapped delegate method.  In there, you can present the web view.

Comment: Thanks Anna for the help, i m sorry for that question i just startet learning swift and objectiv c and sometimes even if i see the answere i dont get it ;)!

Comment: OK, no problem.  Try making the changes like in the linked question.  If you get it working, you can answer this question yourself.  Otherwise, update this question with the new code and problem.

Comment: Small added question Anna (or should i start a new topic for that) is there a way to see what "Annotation" is selected? i tried it with self.title to get the title of info1/info2

Comment: In calloutAccessoryControlTapped, the annotation selected is `annotationView.annotation`.  To get access to custom properties, etc, you'll need to do something similar to what was done in viewForAnnotation (check the type using `is`, cast it using `as`, etc).

Comment: oki thanks ... ll try to get this somehow done even if its looks ways to complex for my skills yet :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            //1

            var lat1:CLLocationDegrees = 40.748708
            var long1:CLLocationDegrees = -73.985643
            var latDelta1:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
            var longDelta1:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

            var span1:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta1, longDelta1)
            var location1:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat1, long1)
            var region1:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location1, span1)

            Map.setRegion(region1, animated: true)


            var info1 = CustomPointAnnotation()
            info1.coordinate = location1
            info1.title = "Test Title1!"
            info1.subtitle = "Subtitle1"
            info1.imageName = "1.png"

            Map.addAnnotation(info1)



            //2


            var lat2:CLLocationDegrees = 41.748708
            var long2:CLLocationDegrees = -72.985643
            var latDelta2:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
            var longDelta2:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

            var span2:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta2, longDelta2)
            var location2:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat2, long2)
            var region2:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location2, span2)




            var info2 = CustomPointAnnotation()
            info2.coordinate = location2
            info2.title = "Test Title2!"
            info2.subtitle = "Subtitle2"
            info2.imageName = "2.png"
            Map.addAnnotation(info2)



    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

        if control == annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
            println("Disclosure Pressed! \(self.title)")
        }
    }






    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
        if !(annotation is CustomPointAnnotation) {
            return nil
        }

        let reuseId = "test"

        var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
        if anView == nil {
            anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            anView.canShowCallout = true
            anView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.buttonWithType(.InfoDark) as UIButton
        }
        else {
            anView.annotation = annotation
        }

        //Set annotation-specific properties **AFTER**
        //the view is dequeued or created...

        let cpa = annotation as CustomPointAnnotation
        anView.image = UIImage(named:cpa.imageName)

        return anView
    }
```