# Swift annotations not displaying correctly following region change

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have the following function to determine the latitude/longitude of an address contained in a text field (`searchAddress`) to create a map region with this location as it's center and then add annotations firstly for this location and secondly for store locations that are stored in a Parse backend.

When the `map view` is first opened the `searchAddress` text field is preset with the users default address and the initial call to the function from `viewDidLoad`. It works as I had intended.  However the user can then type a different address in this field and click a "Search" button which then also calls the same function and the second time. It works occasionally but generally does not display the annotations.

If I click "Search" again so the region does not change then the annotations are displayed correctly.  I assume this is a timing issue and related to the time it takes to redraw the map when I change the region, as sometimes the annotations appear the first time but mostly they don't.  And if I repeat the search without changing the address it works fine.  Thanks in advance, I have been stuck on this and can't find a solution. Here's the code:

```
func addMapAnotations () {
        // var searchLocation = preferredDeliveryLocation.text
        var geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        var address = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(searchAddress.text, completionHandler: {
            (placemarks: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if let placemark = placemarks?[0] as? CLPlacemark {
                var latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.1
                var lonDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.1
                var span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)
                address = placemark.location.coordinate
                println(placemark.location.coordinate.latitude)
                println("Inside geocoder lititude: \(address.latitude)")
                println("Inside geocoder longitude: \(address.longitude)")
                var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(address.latitude, address.longitude)
                var region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
                self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

                var tempLocationObject = self.currentUser
                var searchAnnotation = NewCustomPointAnnotation(coordinate: address, title: "", subtitle: "", locationObject: tempLocationObject!, locationCategory: "")
                self.annotationCategory = "homeLocation"
                searchAnnotation.locationCategory = "homeLocation"
                searchAnnotation.coordinate = address
                searchAnnotation.title = "Search address"
                searchAnnotation.subtitle = "Search for delivery locations near by..."
                // self.map.addAnnotation(MKPlacemark(placemark: placemark))
                self.map.addAnnotation(searchAnnotation)
            }
        })

        self.queryCurrent.whereKey("country", equalTo: "Australia")
        // self.queryCurrent.whereKey("State", equalTo: state)
        self.queryCurrent.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {
                        println(object.objectId)
                        var latitude = object["latitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees
                        var longitude = object["longitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees
                        var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
                        var deliveryAnnotation = NewCustomPointAnnotation(coordinate: location, title: "", subtitle: "", locationObject: object, locationCategory: "")
                        self.annotationCategory = "deliveryLocation"
                        deliveryAnnotation.locationCategory = "deliveryLocation"
                        deliveryAnnotation.coordinate = location
                        deliveryAnnotation.title = object["name"] as! String
                        deliveryAnnotation.subtitle = "Click to select this location"
                        deliveryAnnotation.locationObject = object
                        println("Annotation 1: \(deliveryAnnotation.description)")
                        println("Object ID: \(deliveryAnnotation.locationObject.objectId)")
                        self.map.addAnnotation(deliveryAnnotation)
                    }
                }

            } else {
                println("No locations found")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have fixed this problem by adding dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier logic to my viewForAnnotation delegate and the pins are now displaying all the time. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25202613/mapkit-in-swift-part-2)